# ListView view recycling with CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I'm inflating two different layouts for a ListView. Everything works until I start scrolling down where the 2 different layouts begin being applied randomly. I've followed other examples on here but I just can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Date date = new Date();
    private OfferList[] offers;
    private String nameCompare = "";

    CustomAdapter (OfferList[] offers, FetchItemsTask fetchItemsTask) { 
         this.offers = offers;
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();          
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            if (nameCompare.equalsIgnoreCase(offers[position].getCustomerName())) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_offer_group, null);
            }
            else {
                nameCompare = offers[position].getCustomerName();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_offer, null);
            }
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.color = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.color_stock);
            holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.offerStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_status);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } 
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(offers[position].getName());
        holder.carStockColor.setText(offers[position].getYear() + " " + offers[position].getVehicleMake());
        java.util.Date time1 = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(offers[position].getModified()));
        holder.time.setText(time1.toString().substring(0, 11) + " | ");
        holder.offerStatus.setText(offers[position].getStatus());
        return convertView;

    }

public class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView color;
        TextView time;
        TextView offerStatus;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the following methods:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

These will let the listview know how many types of views you have and which position is of which type. This will prevent the listview from passing the incorrect convertview type into your getView method.

EDIT:

Let's take a step back. The reason you are seeing this problem is ListView is passing the incorrect convertView into your getView() method. The default getViewTypeCount() returns 1, so listView assumes you only have one view type. You are using two types of views for your rows: R.layout.list_offer_group, and R.layout.list_offer. When convertView is not null, you are not checking to see which layout convertView is -- in some cases it will be the incorrect layout.

To remedy this:

override getViewTypeCount to return 2, since you have two different types. Override getItemViewType to use your group/non-group logic

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  if (nameCompare.equalsIgnoreCase(offers[position].getCustomerName())) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

This is now returning 0 for groups and 1 for non-groups. Then we can use getItemViewType() in getView to determine which view we are using, so:

```
        if (nameCompare.equalsIgnoreCase(offers[position].getCustomerName())) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_offer_group, null);
        }
        else {
            nameCompare = offers[position].getCustomerName();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_offer, null);
        }
```

becomes:

```
        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_offer_group, null);
        }
        else {
            nameCompare = offers[position].getCustomerName();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_offer, null);
        }
```

This should fix your behavior since now ListView knows you have 2 view types (getViewTypeCount) and which rows in your list are of which type (getItemViewType). It will no longer pass a convertView of type group into a getView call for a row of type non-group and vice versa.

Comment: The type count would return 2, since I'm using 2 layouts. How would the getItemViewType work in my case?

Comment: In your case just return 0 or 1 based on the view type.

Comment: so i dont need to change my getView() method? just implement the other two?

Comment: Edited answer to better explain the problem, and how my proposed solution fixes it.

Comment: This still doesn't work; the first row is changing to the other layout if I scroll down and back to the first row. Could it be something with the holder (set/getTag)?